# How do I show that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_3$?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

More generally, what is the best tactic for proving that two groups are not isomorphic to each other when they are of the same cardinality?

Comment: Suppose there is such in isomorphism then get a contradiction

Comment: $(0,1)$ has order $3$ whereas there is no element in Z having order 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, it's easy: $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_3$ has an element whose order is $3$, whereas $\mathbb Z$ has no such element.

In general, thinking about the orders of the elements is a good approach.