# Is $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_3\cong\mathbb{Z}$ as modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, direct-product

I'm studying module theory, and I'm trying to prove whether $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_3\cong\mathbb{Z}$ as modules. If i construct the map $\mu :\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_3\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ sending $(a,[b])\mapsto 3a+b$, where we associate $[0]$ with $0$, $[1]$ with $1$ and $[2]$ with $2$, I would expect $\mu$ to be an isomorphism of modules. Or is there a problem with my use of residual classes? I feel a bit like this map is not well defined, but I can't put my finger on why.

Comment: Well, if you defined it only when $b=0,1,2$ then there is no problem with it being well defined. However, it is clearly not a homomorphism. For example, $(0, [2])+(0,[1])=(0, [0])$ is mapped to $0$, but $\mu(0,[2])+\mu(0,[1])=2+1=3$.

Comment: They are not isomorphic since the 1st one has [torsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_(algebra)).

Comment: @Mark ah, thank you that makes total sense. I guess maybe then they are not isomorphic, as the most obvious map between the two domains is not even an homomorphism, it would be hard to come up with one that is further an isomorphism

Comment: @slowpoke They are indeed not isomorphic. See the comment above.

Comment: @AnneBauval is it always that the torsion part of the two domains needs to be isomorphic? (for the domains to be isomorphic)

Comment: The torsion submodules $T(M),T(N)$ of two isomorphic modules $M,N$ are trivially isomorphic (by restriction of the isomorphism between $M$ and $N$).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you again, that makes sense!

Comment: This answer your question: [How do I show that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_3$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2547208/how-do-i-show-that-mathbbz-is-not-isomorphic-to-mathbbz-times-mathbb) ("$\Bbb Z$-module" is synonym of "abelian group", and an isomorphism of abelian groups is nothing more than a group isomorphism between abelian groups).

Comment: @AnneBauval I does thank you again :)